# Stuck between "Name Can Be Simplified" and "Type arguments cannot be inferred"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper, .net-4.5

Visual Studio seems to be fighting with itself, as it keeps bouncing back and forth between telling me I have too much type information and not enough.

If I use the following function call:

```
// 2. Invoke YLT download on the view.
return ReturnResultOrThrowError<double[]>(
    () => _broker.GetYLT.TryGetValue(new GetYLT.Parameters(view, options)));
```

Visual Studio (both 2015 and a fresh 2017 install - both with ReSharper) give me the hint `IDE0001 Name can be simplified` and suggests refactoring to the following:

```
// 2. Invoke YLT download on the view.
return ReturnResultOrThrowError(
    () => _broker.GetYLT.TryGetValue(new GetYLT.Parameters(view, options)));
```

[image: Suggested Refactoring]

As soon as I accept the proposed refactoring, I now get a compile error:
`The type arguments for the method ...ReturnResultOrThrowError<T> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

[image: Compile Error]

What exactly does it want me to do here?

I'm a "0 errors 0 warnings" kind of guy, so I hate when a code style suggestion such as this has to go ignored - especially if it simplifies the code. Not sure if the fact that my VS has Resharper is having an impact or not.

The function definition in question here is:

`private T ReturnResultOrThrowError<T>(Func<CachedResult<T>.Atom> getResultAtom)`

Comment: What does `TryGetValue` return?

Comment: Your question is "one way to write the code gives me an informative message and the other produces an error; which one should I choose?"  I would choose the one that lets the code compile; is there some compelling benefit to choosing the one that causes an error? If the advice given is bad advice, ignore it. And consider reporting this as a bug; the light bulb should not make a suggestion that results in broken code.

Comment: What's the signature of `GetYLT.TryGetValue` method?

Comment: Just to clarify - this is Visual Studio, not ReSharper. You can easily tell because VS gives all diagnostics an ID, such as `IDE0001`, and ReSharper doesn't.

Comment: It should really be a bug report for Visual Studio.